# Creating reports in Java without using a database

Tags: java, report

Is there a simple way to create reports in Java without using a database (like SQL)?

What I want to do is to get a number of strings in an ArrayList of objects and then put them on a printable report. Also, i want to put values from a comma-separated file to the printable report. I've found this [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) but, based from what I've understood, it's not possible to design the report using this. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports), it's the most common open source tool for reporting in the Java world, and you can create reports from multiple data sources, not only data bases.

Comment: Does it include a GUI for designing the report?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have JasperReports. Is there some place where I can learn/study how to use it? (and it seems I need ANT installed on my PC, does this mean that if I compile the project and turned into an executable, the user would need ANT installed on their machine?)

Comment: AFAIK ANT is not required for using Jaspe, only for compiling it from sources. This [book](http://www.apress.com/9781590599273) is a nice starting point, and take a look at the [tutorial](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish//jasperreportswebsite/JR%20Website/jasperreports_tutorial.html).

Comment: How are you planning to distribute the project? As far as I know, Ant isn't a dependency of JasperReports though other libraries are: http://www.installationwiki.org/JasperReports

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I downloaded the ZIP file and not the JAR file of JasperReports. Should I have downloaded the latter if I want to implement JasperReports on my project? If not, what should I get?

Comment: @ChipMcCormick I'm planning to distribute the project through our group's website, if it ever passes my professors.

Comment: Download the one with the required libraries, as per the tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Reports are view, separate from the source of data.  I don't see how a report would know the difference between a database and a list of strings.

Data is data, regardless of where it comes from.   I didn't bother to read the link you included, because tying a report to a particular type of data doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I added 'not using a database' since most report 'makers' i've found (and have used) uses a database. I didn't know that it was possible to create reports without using a database such as SQL.